Mocking with Jasmine.createSpyObj not working as it should or my error?
So I'm testing the function grabFrame from my FrameService class and an error comes up when I mock the class dependency with Jasmine.createSpyObj:
service.ts:
import {Service} from "./service";

export class FrameService {

    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

    constructor(private service?: Service) {
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    }

    async grabFrame(): Promise<ImageData> {
        const video = document.getElementById("stream") as HTMLVideoElement
        const b64 = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
        const image_frame = await this.service.library.convertBase64ToRGBA(b64, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
        return image_frame;
    }
}

this.service is set in the class constructor so, instead, I'm passing a mock when I create a FrameService object in the test:
service.spec.ts:
describe('FrameService', () => {
    let frameService;
    let mockService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service', {
        library: jasmine.createSpyObj('library', {
            convertBase64ToRGBA: jasmine.createSpy('convertBase64ToRGBA').and.resolveTo(mockImageData)
        })

        // passing mock dependency
        frameService = new FrameService(mockService);
    });
  
    it('should return an ImageData object', async () => {
        const imageData = await frameService.grab_frame();
        expect(imageData).toBeDefined();
        expect(imageData).toEqual(jasmine.any(ImageData));
    });
}

When I run the test I get the following error:
TypeError: this.service.library.convertBase64ToRGBA is not a function

According to Jasmine documentation createSpyObj receives as second parameter an "Array of method names to create spies for, or Object whose keys will be method names and values the returnValue.", so I also tried to mock Service as follows but still didn't work:
mockNativeService = jasmine.createSpyObj('NativeService', {
    library2: jasmine.createSpyObj('library2',  {
        convertBase64ToRGBA: Promise.resolve(mockImageData)
    })
});

But then I modified the mock as follows:
mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service', {
    library: jasmine.createSpyObj('library', ['convertBase64ToRGBA'])
});
mockService.library.convertBase64ToRGBA = jasmine.createSpy('convertBase64ToRGBA').and.resolveTo(mockImageData);
// mockService.library.convertBase64ToRGBA = jasmine.createSpy('convertBase64ToRGBA').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockImageData)) also works

The test worked fine.
Isn't this the same thing? Would this mean that Jasmine.createSpyObj is not working properly?
I expected the first or second attemps of mocking using Jasmine.createSpyObj to work the same way as the solution I found.

What's this.service? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
